# Adicionar valor a uma propriedade <script>

Tags: javascript, html5, aplicação-web

Olá, tenho o seguinte código

```html
<html>

//=======Teste1========
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="http://modulo.que.sera.carregado.js"
  data-token="">
</script>

//=======Teste2========
<script>
    scriptTeste = function() {

    var dados = JSON.parse(localStorage.dados);
    var node = document.createElement("script");
    var att = document.createAttribute("data-token");
    att.value = dados.token;
    node.setAttributeNode(att);   

    document.getElementById("idBody").prepend(node);
    }
    scriptTeste();
</script>

</html>
```

O valor do **data-token** virá pela sessão do usuário, e preciso adicioná-lo ao script.
Após o carregamento deste script inicial deverá ser carregado um outro Script que depende que os modulos de primeiro já estejam carregados.

Adicionei no exemplo acima os dois códigos que testei.

O ***Teste1*** funcionou somente quando deixei o valor do data-token fixo.
O ***Teste2*** não funcionou porque o segundo script que será carregado não espera este primeiro script finalizar o carregamento dos módulos.

Comment: Mas o primeiro script irá depender do valor do token do segundo?

Comment: Não, o primeiro script depende do token da Session, e o segundo script depende do carregamento completo do modulo que o primeiro carrega.

Comment: Tenta substituindo `scriptTeste();` por `window.onload = scriptTeste;`.

Comment: Tente colocando o atributo `defer` e `onload="scriptTeste()"` na tag: `<script defer onload="scriptTeste()"...`

Comment: Bom dia, isso eu havia tentado também. Não funcionou.